# Batch file that searches for a folder with the same name as a local file and moves said file to the located folder not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

So I am trying to create a batch file that will take a pdf file in the same directory as the batch file and output the file name (sans extension). I used this code to accomplish this:

```
@echo off

for /r "C:\Users\me\Test Folder" %%G in (*.pdf) do set "name=%%~nG"
```

This works fine. The next step is to search another directory and find a directory within the searched directory whose name matches the output of the above code (stored in the %name% variable). Here's what I tried:

```
dir "P:\Accounting\Acc Pay" | find %name% | set "loc=%%~dp"
```

The goal of the above code was to find only the directories that had the same name as the original pdf file and then set the drive and path of the output to a variable %loc%. I think this is where I messed up.

Once the path to the folder is set to %loc%, I then am supposed to finish with this line:

```
move .\*.pdf %loc%
```

This would take all the pdf files (there will only be one in the directory at once) in the directory with the batch file and move it to the path currently stored in the %loc% variable.

In total the code looks like this:

```
@echo off

for /r "C:\Users\me\Test Folder" %%G in (*.pdf) do set "name=%%~nG"

for /r %%A in ('dir "P:\Accounting\Acc Pay" | find %name%') do set "loc=%%~dpA"

move .\*.pdf %loc%
```

However, the code seems to move the pdf file into the same location it was already in (ie the folder with the batch file). I assume the %loc% variable is not working properly. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is the folder to search always a direct child of `"P:\Accounting\AccPay"` or may it be buried somewhere "down the tree"?

Comment: it is always a direct child. Within the AccPay folder there are multiple folders, one for each vendor company. Within those folders are only files.

Comment: `for /r "C:\Users\me\Test" %%G in (*.pdf) do move "%%G" "P:\Accounting\AccPay\%%~nG"`?

Comment: Or use `if exist` instead. e.g. `@For /R "C:\Users\me\Test" %%G In (*.pdf) Do @If Exist "P:\Accounting\AccPay\%%~nG\" Move /Y "%%G" "P:\Accounting\AccPay\%%~nG"`

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, that worked! So normally, the file name won't match the folder name exactly. Instead the folder will be named something like this (Example Company) and the pdf file will be named something like this (Example Company-Invoice 12345). Anyway I could still make this work?

Comment: 'tis your code that is failing. You are not setting `loc` because the `for` command has invalid syntax, and the `move` command thus has no destination and hence also fails. The problem is the pipe (`|`) which needs to be escaped (`^|`) to tell `cmd` that it is part of the single-quoted code, not of the `for` itself. Re last comment - please create a new question as we chase neither moving goalposts nor wild geese. And "anyway" is an adverb meaning "whatever else is happening, without considering other things" not "[is there] any way" as you mean (Ans: probably, exemplify in a new question).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Magoo said (`^|`). And you surely want to add the following switches for the `dir` command: `/b` for "bare format" (name only) and `/ad` for "Attribute Directory" to return folder names only. `find` needs its's argument quoted, and for safety, the destination for the `move` command should also be quoted. Your `find` could benefit from `/i` to make it case-insensitive.

I personally would do it with nested loops to avoid creating superflouos variables:

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\Users\me\Test Folder" %%G in (*.pdf) do (
  for /r %%A in ('dir /b /ad "P:\Accounting\Acc Pay" ^| find /i "%%~nG"') do (
    move "%%G" "%%~dpA"
  )
)
```

Bonus: should there be more than one `.pdf` file (maybe after the Weekend or Holidays), this would process all of them correctly in one go.

Depending on your naming structures, consider replacing `find /i "%%~nG"` with `findstr /iblc:"%%~nG"` (see `findstr /?`to find out what the switches mean)

(Note to prevent confusion: `findstr` is the only command (as far as I'm aware) that supports concatenating switches into one. `/iblc` is the same as `/i /b /l /c`)