# MD command creating generic file instead of a directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've written a simple batch file to move `.pdf` files to certain folders located on a file system. Currently, the code checks to see if a folder with a company's name exists (`P:\invoices\%company%`). If the folder exists then the code checks to see if a subfolder called `2021` is located at `P:\invoices\%company%\2021`. If the `2021` folder already exists, the code moves the `.pdf` file to that `2021` folder.

However, if the `2021` subfolder does not exist, then the code is supposed to create a `2021` folder at `P:\invoices\%company%\2021`. I used the `md` command to do this but it creates a generic file called `2021` instead of a folder. Then the `.pdf` file disappears into thin air, presumably because it is moving it into a file instead of a folder.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off

for /r "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" %%G in (*.pdf) do set "name=%%~nG"

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=-" %%i in ("%name%") do set "company=%%i"

if exist "P:\invoices\%company%" do (
    if exist "P:\invoices\%company%\2021" do (
        move /y "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" "P:\invoices\%company%\2021"
    )
    else do (
        md "P:\invoices%\company%\2021"
        move /y "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" "P:\invoices%\company%\2021"
    )
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for /r "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" %%G in (*.pdf) do set "name=%%~nG"`, should look more like `for /r "C:\Users\me\Scan" %%G in (*.pdf) do set "name=%%~nG"`. However, all that would do, would be to create a single variable, `%name%`, containing the full path of the last file found with an extension beginning with `.pdf`. Is that really what you intend it to do? Also `for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=-" %%i in ("%name%") do set "company=%%i"` is the same as `for /f "delims=-" %%i in ("%name%") do set "company=%%i"`; `if exist "P:\invoices\%company%" do (` should be `if exist "P:\invoices\%company%\" (`.

Comment: …and `if exist "P:\invoices\%company%\2021" do (` should be `if exist "P:\invoices\%company%\2021\" (`. Also the two lines `)` and `else do (` should be one line `) else (`. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `if /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information. You should also do that with `for /?`, to learn more about `for /r` and `for /f` too.

Comment: And to address the title:  `md` didn't do anything here, you moved a file into a file named `2021`

Comment: @AnonCoward why did "md" create a file instead of a directory?

Comment: @Pickinanameainteasy It didn't do that.  It didn't even run, or if it does run, it's producing an error.  I'm not sure how it happend in the first place, but once this script ends up with a file called "2021", it will keep overwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

:: This ensures that the original environment is restored on termination
SETLOCAL

:: Use variable so year needs to be changed in only 1 place
set "year=2021"

:: And representing destination parent-directory
set "destparent=P:\invoices"

:: read the filenames from the tree
for /r "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" %%G in (*.pdf) do (
 REM %%G has full filename, %%~nG the name part only
 for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%i in ("%%~nG") do (
  REM %%i has company name
  REM Optional to auto-create company-directory begin
  REM force Company directory to exist
  MD "%destparent%\%%i" 2>nul >nul
  REM Optional to auto-create company-directory end

  REM If company directory truly exists
  if exist "%destparent%\%%i\." (
   rem force year subdirectory to exist
    MD "%destparent%\%%i\%year%" 2>nul >nul
    rem does subdirectory now exist?
    if exist "%destparent%\%%i\%year%\." (
        move /y "%%G" "%destparent%\%%i\%year%\"
    ) else (
     echo "%destparent%\%%i\%year%" directory not found
   )
  ) else (
    echo "%destparent%\%%i" directory not found
  )
 )
)
```

**[Untested - apply to dummy directories for verification]**

OP code problems:

The `for /r ... %%G` will assign to `name` the name of the *LAST* file encountered, which will be the from the very last directory in the subtree that contains a file passing the name-mask `*.pdf` Then the value installed in `name` is only used to derive the company-name.

`company` is set up from the part before the first `-` in *name*. The part between the first and second `-` in *name* (or end of *name*) is assigned to `%%j` and never used. OP should consider the possibility that the actual company-name is hyphenated.

OP's code uses `if ... DO (` (more than once). `DO` is illegal here and must be omitted.

OP's code uses `else ... DO (` . `DO` is illegal here and must be omitted. The `else` keyword **must** be on the same physical line as the `)` for the *true* `code block` (parenthesised sequence of statements)

The `MOVE` statements attempt to move **ALL** of the `.pdf` files in the selected subtree-rootdirectory to the destination, regardless of file's company-code or the fact that the selected company-code may be from the `.pdf` at the deepest level of the tree.

---

I've attempted to fix the code to do what I suspect the actual intention of the code is, being to move the .pdf files from the subtree to each file's appropriate `destination\company\2021` directory, creating directories as necessary.

I will emphasise one again that this code is **UNTRIED**.

As a suggestion for testing, on a copy of the batch, I would replace each `MD` and `MOVE` statement with `ECHO MD` and `ECHO MOVE` respectively, and omit all of the redirection statements `2>nul` and `>nul` (which are intended to suppress unwanted messages)

Finally, I'd insert a `PAUSE` line before the final `goto :eof` to permit the resultant proposed-list-of-changes from disappearing as I suspect that we may be dealing with a case of Heretical Clickitis.

Comment: thanks, lots of good explanations here. I didn't realize else had to be in the same line as if, I'm coming from python so it works a bit different. the 'for /r' is ok in this scenario because there will only ever be one .pdf file in the folder at a time. I will look into fixing the code so that it addresses hyphenated company names since there are a few of those.

Comment: It looks like 'do' is only used in 'for' statements and not 'if/else' that's good to know. I don't want my code to create a company folder if it doesn't exist because there are already established company files, and I don't want to create a bunch of new ones with different names.

Comment: The point with `for /r` is that it scans subdirectories. If you wish to scan a single directory, then I'd use `for "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" %%G in (*.pdf) do (` although this would assign simply `filename.pdf` to `%%G` (no path). You would then need to use `"C:\Users\me\Scan\%%G" as the sourcefile in the `move`. As for not wanting to auto-create the company directory, simply omit the lines between `rem description begin` and `rem description end` and the script should respond with the `"%destparent%\%%i" directory not found` error message.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd suggest you try the task:

As a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@For /R "%UserProfile%\Scan" %%G In (*-*.pdf
) Do @For /F "Delims=-" %%i In ("%%~nG"
) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%%~dpG." "P:\invoices\%%i\2021" "%%~nxG" /Mov 1>NUL
```

Or, as a single line entered in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```sh
For /R "%UserProfile%\Scan" %G In (*-*.pdf) Do @For /F "Delims=-" %i In ("%~nG") Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%~dpG." "P:\invoices\%i\2021" "%~nxG" /Mov 1>NUL
```

*Just change the paths, `%UserProfile%\Scan` and `P:\invoices`, as needed.*

**[Edit /]**

If you want you own code fixing, according to the comments I've already made, and to fix your two previously unmentioned typos `md "P:\invoices%\company%\2021"` and `move /y "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" "P:\invoices%\company%\2021`, which should have read `md "P:\invoices\%company%\2021"` and `move /y "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" "P:\invoices\%company%\2021` respectively. Then this is how I'd suggest you could have fixed it:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /R "C:\Users\me\Scan" %%G In (*.pdf) Do (
    Set "name=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "Delims=-" %%i In ("!name!") Do (
        EndLocal
        Set "company=%%i"
    )
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Exist "P:\invoices\!company!\" (
        If Not Exist "P:\invoices\!company!\2021\" (
            MD "P:\invoices\!company!\2021"
    )
    If Exist "P:\invoices\!company!\2021\" (
        Move /Y "%%G" "P:\invoices\!company!\2021"
    )
    EndLocal
)

Pause
```

Note: As you are both creating and using variables within the same parenthesized code blocks, I have used delayed expansion to ensure that your updated variables are maintained throughout.

---

Please now compare my upper answer with your fixed version below it, and see why, I offered the much shorter and simpler solution initially.

Comment: This code does work. I have tested as a batch file and pasting into cmd. However, it copies the file instead of moving it (ie cut and pasting). I also, am trying to learn how to write batch myself, so while you're code does work, it just feels like you doing the work for me, that's why I responded to another post. I was able to tweak my code to finally work. Thanks for the tip on turning echo on that helped me troubleshoot it.

Comment: `code`for /r "C:\Users\me\Scan\" %%G in (*.pdf) do set "name=%%~nG"

for /f "delims=-" %%i in ("%name%") do set "company=%%i"

if not exist "P:\invoices\%company%\2021" md "P:\invoices\%company%\2021"

move /y "C:\Users\me\Scan\*.pdf" "P:\invoices\%company%\2021"`code`

Comment: You are absolutely wrong, you have obviously tried to change my code instead of running exactly what I posted. You have assumed that `Robocopy.exe`, by its name cannot move a file, please open a Command Prompt window, type `robocopy /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. In that output you should specifically take a look at the `/Mov` option I used, and all will be revealed. Also you should be aware, that it will create the destination directory, if it doesn't already exist, hence the reason I didn't need, at any point, to use the `MD`/`MkDir` command. Please try again!

Comment: Also, @Pickinanameainteasy, I wasn't just doing the work for you, I told you exactly what the problems were with your own code in the comment section, this answer was provided as an addition, because it's simpler, and more robust. In addition to it, if you take a look at the answer to [your last, almost the same, question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65709380), most of what I told you, had already been shown in that answer, you just seemed not to have studied it, or base your own code on it, before posting it here.

Comment: @ Compo look I'm just an accountant with a limited knowledge of scripting. I want people to help troubleshoot my code so I can write simple scripts in the future without relying on help from this site. My questions are similar because I'm still in the process of understanding batch. I'm not a coder, nor do I plan to be one, I just need to understand how to move files efficiently. I'm only now grasping "for loops" because of these scripts I've written. While you're code does get the job done, it doesn't make sense to me and I don't have the time to learn how it works.

Comment: But you have not acknowledged that my code does solve your issue, and does actually move directories, and create any which do not already exist, as I wrote it to do, but you categorically stated it didn't. When I post an answer I expect that it is tested as is, before a statement is made suggesting an issue it exhibits. You said that it copies, and not moves, I said that it didn't, and explained where in the usage information, the evidence lies. As I've already told you, I explained which lines were invalid code, and told you what those lines should have said, I also told you how to debug it!

Comment: @Pickinanameainteasy, I have also, tried my best to add another code example to my answer, to better reflect your provided code methodology, but with the fixed in place I'd already advised in my earlier comments, and with a couple of extra previously unmentioned typos shown to you too. Feel free to test this one, study it and learn from it. Thank you.

Comment: I have also just edited that lower code, as I noted in [your comment under another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66355020/md-command-creating-generic-file-instead-of-a-directory/66356080?noredirect=1#comment117337838_66358965), that you do not want new company directories creating, if they don't already exist, just missing `2021` directories.

Comment: Thank you for your help!